# Accessing the message body before or after received to inbox

Tags: android

`
    package com.example.smsTest;

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";            
        if (bundle != null)
        { 
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
           for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            str += "SMS from " + m sgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";        
        }
        //---display the new SMS message---
        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }                       
}
}`
```

This the code whic receives my sms sent..
But i could display it to inbox..
I am trying to decrypt it and den send it to the inbox.. or at least make use of inbox message and decrypt it...
So is there any way to access the text body before or after receiving the message to inbox.

Comment: You already access the "message body" in your code on the 3rd "str +=" row.

Comment: Oh yaa.. n any idea on displayn it in our own app..
should i start an activity in d code immediately after string containing the msg body??